# The numbers in my javascript will not add

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, addition

So I need the code to use addition on random numbers in the array. If the sum is greater then ten, it should say "over" else it would be "under."

`

```
function arraries(){
       var oneten = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
               document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = addy(oneten);  
   }

function addy(oneten){
     var n;
    var output;
    var sum = "";

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        sum += parseFloat(oneten[n])}





    if (sum > 10){
        return "over";

    }
    else { return  "under";}

}
```

The problem here is that the debugger decipher the numbers as strings. While running the sum would equal "1234" instead of 10 (which is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) and thus it will always return "over". How can I make sure that the data will be treat as actually numbers instead of strings? I used parseFloat and parseInt but I got the same results

Comment: Why is `sum` a string?! You don't need to parse as integer or float, because the array already is an array of integers! The real problem is that `sum` is a string for some reason.

Comment: That can answer my question. But earlier ago I I coded " var sum;" and the results in the loop ended up undefined.

Comment: You are implicitly setting sum as a string with the ""'s. Dont do that.

Comment: @JamesClark Set it to an integer, 0.

Comment: That helps. I just set it to equal zero instead and now its fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Mabybe you can try to set sum = 0, because like this js will concatenate into a string instead of into a int

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you declare the `sum` variable as a `number`? Also, you don't need `parseFloat` function, the `oneten` array elements are already typeof `number`.

Another thing - `Math.random() * 10) + 1` loss numbers from the `1 - 10` range and in your case it will return `undefined` because there's no item in the `oneten` array with index `10`. Use `Math.random() * 10` instead, which will return numbers from `0 - 9` range.

```js
function arraries() {
  var oneten = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = addy(oneten);
}

function addy(oneten) {
  var n;
  var output;
  var sum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    sum += oneten[n];
  }
  console.log(sum);

  if (sum > 10) {
    return "over";

  } else {
    return "under";
  }

}

arraries();
```

```html
<p id='demo'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**type coercion in javascript**

```
var s = "1";
var i = 1;

var i = i+1;
// 2    int + int = int
var s2 = s+1;
// "11" str + int = str
var s3 = i+"1";
// "11" int + str = str
```